# how to display an sqli database

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to be able to display the contents of my database but I am not sure how to do this using sqli, any help provided will be appreciated

```
<?php


ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$servername = "server";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "sql1702520";


 // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

I tried to use a mysql query bellow to extract the data from the database, however i have been told that it is not possible to use mysql and sqli

```
/*
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sql1702520 ");
*/


    $conn->close(); 
?>
```

Html to display the database

```
<html>

 <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>image</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
```

Tried using this to display the table data however mysql would be required to do it this way

```
  while( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
    foreach ($row1 as $row){
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php $row['id'] ?></td>
      <td><?php $row['hname'] ?></td>
      <td><?php $row['himage'] ?></td>
      <td><?php $row['hdesc'] ?></td> 
    </tr>
<?php
    }
  }
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
</body>


  </html>
```

Comment: `sql1702520` this is your table name ?

Comment: Use SHOW TABLES AND SHOW COLUMNS if needed.

Answer (score -1):

assuming that your tablename (what looks suspiciously like your database name) for mysqli you would have to use the `mysqli_query` function to send your query.

```
$result = mysql_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM sql1702520 ");
```

and `mysqli_fetch_assoc`for your loop

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

you can ditch the for-each loop. the while loop is sufficient.

for further help an error message would help.